# Request for guidance on sources to help me figure out how to do simple thing

Tags: led, power, switches

I have 9 3w leds (white) and 2 1w leds (blue).  I have one led driver with sufficient output to drive only the white leds (either in series or parallel.)  Therefore, I figured I will get a separate driver for the blues(which have a much lower total power requirement than the whites.)  With a 3 position switch, i would like to have:

Position 1 - both white and blue leds on.

Position 2 - all lights off.

Position 3 - blue lights only on.

This seems like it should be simple.  Any direction on learning how to do this would be welcomed.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you make your title a little bit descriptive of what you are asking?

Answer (score 2):

What you want is a three position two pole rotary switch:

It's circuit is like this:

[image]

The three positions are

```
position 1: contacts 1 & 4 selected -- used for Blue (contact 1) and White (contact 4)
position 2: contacts 2 & 5 selected -- no contacts used (off position)
position 3: contacts 3 & 6 selected -- used for Blue only (contact 3)
```

Connect Blue to terminal 1 and 3, and White to terminal 4.  Leave terminals 2 and 5 disconnected for the center off position.  Also leave terminal 6 disconnected.
Connect your drive voltage for Blue to terminal C1, and White to C2.

One such switch is the ALPS SRBM131300, [available from Mouser](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/ALPS/SRBM131300/?qs=6EGMNY9ZYDRFnYJ9nJc7Tw%3D%3D&kpid=253447547&gclid=CMWhrZ-noMQCFciTfgodqQYA4A) for $5.75.